# Multiple A4 paper(landscape) using css

Tags: php, css, html, printing, media-queries

I am using the following to print A4 size paper (landscape). But When I have more contents in the page, it cannot fit in the paper. So I need a way to apply the same style (A4 landscape) to the next page whenever the content does not fit into the one page.

CSS:

```
 page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
     width: 29.7cm;
     height: 21cm;  
}
@media print {
  body, page {
   margin: 0;
   box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<page size="A4" layout="landscape">
    <table>//many rows</table>
</page>
```

If the rows in the table are more than that of an A4 paper can hold, I want to repeat . I am using php to display lot of data in the table. I am thinking of using  multiple times depending on the number of rows I would retrieve from the database but I don't know how to do it as the table element is already inside the  element. Please help.

Comment: Well, first of all, it isn't really html. There is no element named `<page>` and no attributes named `size` or `layout`. Also, the sizes in the <page> and in the stylesheet don't match.

Comment: I have added the complete script. please check.

Comment: You shouldn't invent your own elements. That is not what html is about. In its current form, your website is a walking time bomb.

Comment: Mr Lister. I am not using it on website.